# Minimum car required to accommodate given people

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I had one coding round where question statement was like this

*You have a given number of friends and seating capacity of their cars now you need to find minimum number of cars required to accommodate them all.

Example:

```
People = [1, 4, 1]
SeatingCapacity = [1, 5, 1]
```

In this case we need minimum `2` cars as number of people on 0th index can adjust with index 1 car.

Example 2:

```
People = [4, 4, 5, 3]
SeatingCapacity = [5, 5, 7, 3]
```

This case answer will be as index 3 people can be accommodate into 0,1,2 or 1,2 index car*

I wrote code like this

```java
int numberOfCars(int[] p, int[] s) {
    int noOfCars=p.length;
    Int extraSeats=0;

    for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++) {
        extraSeats+= (s[i] - p[i]) 
    } 
    for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++) { 
        if(extraSeats-p[i] >=0){
            extraSeats-= p[i] ;
            noOfCars--;
        }
    }
    return noOfCars;
   }
```

However my code failed for many cases as well as it was saying some performance issue.
Can anyone please tell me which cases I missed?

Comment: Have the courtesy to indent your code.

Comment: What does "People = [1, 4, 1]" mean? Are the typos in the problem statement in the original source material, or are they due to you? I wouldn't do some coding challenge if the people behind it couldn't even write a proper, understandable description of the problem.

Comment: @scary wombat: sorry I typed from mobile so didn't get glimpse of indentation

Comment: @kcsquared: this is it in my problem statement, no other example or condition, can you please help me to improve the code?

Comment: @kcsquared: sure I will try, but just can you please give me one example where this code fails? So I can redevelop code keeping such cases in my mind

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved by just greedy approach. Like below:

```
people = [1,4,1]
p = sum(people) //6
cars = [1,5,1]
sort(cars, descending) //cars = [5,1,1]
idx = 0
while(p > 0) { p -= cars[idx]; idx += 1 }
answer = idx
```

Handle the corner case where total capacity in cars is less than number of people.

Complexity : `sorting cars O(n log n) + while loop O(n) = O(n log n)`

Comment: thank you for your solution, just a question, do you know where my approach can fail? I took assumption like capacity won't go beyond number of people, unfortunately I can't verify your solution as that was coding test but I am upvoting your answer, bdw shouldn't you increase idx value in while loop?

Comment: Yea, I didn't write it as a code. `idx` should increase.

Comment: Your approach seems totally wrong to me. Even for the example you gave, the answer should be `3`, but your code will output `1`. Try dry running your code. Also, I'm really not sure how total extra seats is going to help in counting number of cars required.

Comment: I actually decrement the value from total Number of cars, so basically I just get total extra seats and it can accommodate other cars passengers

Comment: I had assumed that the groups of people couldn’t be split from the examples, but that isn’t actually stated anywhere so this greedy solution does work. You could even improve this to O(n) with a quickselect approach.

Comment: Coded the solution in JS and I found that at  last step  `answer = idx + 1` for incrementing the  index is not needed, simply return the index.
Check solution with tests here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/minimum-car-code-challenge?file=readme.md,mincar.test.js,mincar.js)

Comment: @ZR87 I had initially written it as a pseudocode and didn't have `idx+1` in the working loop. I added it upon suggestion of Lowcool, and didn't correct the last line which returns the ans (Initially, it was alright as last processed index would be 0 based, hence idx+1 would be the answer). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

This would be my solution in Javascript:

```
function peopleCars (persons, seats) {
  let numberOfCars = 0;

  let people = persons.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, 0); //Calculate total number of persons

  seats.sort((a,b) => {return b-a}); //Rearrange the total number of seats in each car in ascending order to fill the seats starting from the one that can take the most persons

  while(people > 0) {
    people -= seats[numberOfCars]; //subtract the numbers of seats of each car from the number of persons available. This will now leave us with the remaining people
    numberOfCars += 1 //increment the number of cars to be used.
  }
  return numberOfCars
}

// console.log (peopleCars( [2,1,2,2], [5,4,2,5]));
```